# Assignment to entry in nil map when using http header with Echo golang

Tags: http, go, go-echo

here is my test using testing package and echo web http framework : 
(webserver variable is a global echo instance)

```
func TestRunFunction(t *testing.T){
    req := new(http.Request)
    **req.Header.Set("Authorization","Bearer "+loginToken.Token)**
    rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c := WebServer.NewContext(standard.NewRequest(req, WebServer.Logger()), standard.NewResponse(rec, WebServer.Logger()))
    c.SetPath(path)
    if assert.NoError(t , RunFunction(c)){
        assert.Equal(t,http.StatusOK, rec.Code)
    }
}
```

Im trying to test some function that called by REST GET method, but I get this panic error :

```
panic: assignment to entry in nil map [recovered]
        panic: assignment to entry in nil map
```

The panic is on the line in bold (astrix in the code), when Im trying to set the header. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

The error is self explanatory: `req.Header` is nil; you cannot assign to a nil map.

The solution is to either:

1. Initialize `req.Header` with a new instance of [`net/http.Header`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Header)

   ```
   req.Header = make(http.Header)
   ```
2. Or, create the `req` variable with [`net/http.NewRequest`](https://godoc.org/net/http#NewRequest), which does all the internal initializing for you:

   ```
   req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://example.com/path", nil)
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   req.Header.Set("Authorization","Bearer "+loginToken.Token)
   ```